# Spark: Select dynamic field name during XML load

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While loading a path composed by XML files (+100.000 files) that contain almost the same structure, I need to create a dataframe mapping the XML tag fields to other field names (I'm using alias for this task). I'm using spark-xml library to achieve this goal.

However, there are some specific tag names that occur in some XML files and not in others (ICMS00, ICMS10, ICMS20, etc). Example:

```
<det nItem="1">
    <imposto>
        <ICMS>
            <ICMS00>
                <orig>0</orig>
                <CST>00</CST>
                <modBC>0</modBC>
                <vBC>50.60</vBC>
                <pICMS>12.00</pICMS>
                <vICMS>6.07</vICMS>
            </ICMS00>
        </ICMS>
    </imposto>
</det>
```

```
<det nItem="1">
    <imposto>
        <ICMS>
            <ICMS20>
                <orig>1</orig>
                <CST>10</CST>
            </ICMS20>
        </ICMS>
    </imposto>
</det>
```

The schema while loading without any modification is:

```
-- det: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- imposto: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ICMS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ICMS00: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- CST: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- modBC: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- orig: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- pICMS: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- vBC: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- vICMS: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ICMS20: struct (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- CST: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- orig: long (nullable = true)
```

I need a solution that maps the content of ICMS00 and ICMS20 to same column while creating a dataframe. However I could not find a solution similar to a select using regex or specifying the sub-tag without the fullpath.

The result schema should be similar to:

```
-- det: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- imposto: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ICMS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ICMS: struct (nullable = true) ###common tag name###
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- CST: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- modBC: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- orig: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- pICMS: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- vBC: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- vICMS: double (nullable = true)
```

I already tried to change the schema before selecting fields:

```py
# Transform variable ICMSXX fields to static ICMS
det_schema = df.schema['det'].json()
icms_schema = re.sub(r"ICMS([0-9])+", r"ICMS", det_schema)
det_schema_modified = StructField.fromJson(json.loads(icms_schema))
det_schema_modified.schema

# Explode det (item) and visualize the schema
df_itens = df.select(col('det').cast(det_schema_modified.dataType)).withColumn('det', explode(col('det')))
df_itens.select('det').printSchema()
```

However, it duplicates the schema and giver error when trying to select because of the duplicated field schema:

```
-- det: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- imposto: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ICMS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ICMS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- CST: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- modBC: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- orig: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- pICMS: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- vBC: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- vICMS: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ICMS: struct (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- CST: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- orig: long (nullable = true)
```

My current code:

```py
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='infNFe').load(file_location)

df_itens = df_itens.select(
                    col("det._nItem").alias("id"),
                    col("det.prod.cProd").alias("prod_cProd"),
                    col("det.prod.cEAN").alias("prod_cEAN"),
                    col("det.prod.NCM").alias("prod_NCM"),
                    col("det.imposto.ICMS.ICMS00.modBC").alias("ICMS_modBC"),
                    col("det.imposto.ICMS.ICMS00.vBC").alias("ICMS_vBC"),
                    col("det.imposto.ICMS.ICMS20.modBC").alias("ICMS_modBC"),
                    col("det.imposto.ICMS.ICMS20.vBC").alias("ICMS_vBC"),
                    etc.. for ICMS40, ICMS50, ICMS60, ...
```

Is there a way to select using regex or to handle these variable XML tag names while loading these files?

Something similar to:

```
df_itens.select(col("det.imposto.ICMS.ICMS*.modBC").alias("ICMS_modBC"))
```

or

```
df_itens.select(col("det.*.*.*.modBC").alias("ICMS_modBC"))
```

Comment: You should be able to specify the schema before you load the files. That way, you would not have to worry about the format. Let me know if that works out.

Comment: I already tried this solution but in this case I will have different column fields for ICMS00 and ICMS20. I would like to have the sub-fields of these tags into the same column.